# Create JSOnObject using JSon.net manually

Tags: json.net, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using [Facebook C# SDK.](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) In general it works fine but for a unit test I have to create a JSONObject on my own. First I tried with "JSONObject.Add" but I did not find out how to write subnodes then. So I started working with XML and using "SerializeXMLNode". This works fine, so now I have the JSON-String. But how could I create a JSONObject from this string now??

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by this. Could you post a code sample?

Comment: are you wanting to utilize json.net?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Net;

//

string jsonString = [YOUR JSON-STRING];

var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(jsonUrl);
```

I hope this helps.